# JPA Join query inside @Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have three model class there are - User, Menu, Sub-menu.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CBR_USER")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "CBR_USER_ID")
    private Integer cbrUserId;
    @Column(name = "LOG_IN_ID")
    private String logInId;
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "FULL_NAME")
    private String FULL_NAME;
    private String EMAIL;
    private String PHONE;
    private Integer ROLE_ID;
    private String DESIGNATION;
    private String branchId;
    private Integer IS_VALID;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "Conf_menu_Access", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CBR_USER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private List<Menu> menuList;

}
```

Menu class is :

```
   @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CONF_MENU")
    public class Menu {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_menu")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_menu", sequenceName = "seq_menu", allocationSize = 1)
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private String url;
        private Integer accessBy;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "menuId")
        private List<SubMenu> menuList;

    }
```

and sub-menu class is

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "conf_sub_menu")
public class SubMenu {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_sub_menu")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_sub_menu", sequenceName = "seq_sub_menu", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "MENU_ID")
    private Integer menuId;
    private String name;
    private String url;
}
```

after compile my code it's generate another mapping table name as

> Conf_menu_Access

this table map user access able menu , it's define in User class.

now  i need  to implement a sql query which is

```
SELECT ID ,NAME,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT ID FROM CONF_MENU_ACCESS WHERE CBR_USER_ID = 150 AND ID = CMA.ID )>0 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS ACCESSBY 
FROM CONF_MENU CMA ORDER BY ID ASC
```

i want to write this query inside  ***@Query*** tag, any one can help me how to do this......

Comment: `@Query(value = "<your query>", nativeQuery = true)`.

Comment: it's not working...

2019-04-30 12:30:10.754 ERROR 5396 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ID ,NAME,
    CASE 
  WHEN (SELECT ID FROM CONF_MENU_ACCESS WHERE CBR_USER_ID = 150 AND ID = CMA.ID )>0 
THEN 1  ELSE 0 
    END AS ACCESSBY 
FROM CONF_MENU CMA ORDER BY ID ASC", nativeQuery = true)
```

It might be that column name which you are using it should match the column name in the database and the error which is coming is may be that the column name you are passing is of entity field.

Comment: I think problem in query not in code.Check its running SQL Developer?